# Can the locations of easter eggs be found in the game files?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

The [official KSP wiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/List_of_easter_eggs) lists several easter eggs - objects which can be found on the surfaces of the various planets.

Can you find the positions of these objects somewhere in the game files?

Comment: You'd probably have to decompile the game map to figure that out.  I don't think it's in a human readable format.  Still would be interesting to find out, though!

Comment: There are mods for locating them.  Can't point you to one at the moment though.

Comment: @MBraedley it would be interesting to know if these mods read the game files or come with a list of known locations. I mostly want to know because I want to know if it makes sense to search for more easter eggs. When all locations were extracted from the game files, it would be pointless to try to find any more.

Comment: @Philipp: yeah, it's hard to know without decompiling the plugin dll.

Comment: [Here's the mod](http://kerbalspaceport.com/isa-mapsat-3-3-4/) I was referring to.  Hope that at least helps a bit.